# How to know what thread is emiting interruptions? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, thread-safety, pthreads

I'm working on an application that has 8 threads running 8 different asynchronous things simultaneously. Sometimes 1 of them releases a Segfault and I can't find which one is, the error is a rare occurrence and I can't reproduce, happens once every 20 runs.
There is a way to know which one is emitting the interruption? Or at least know if a thread is active in a moment?

I'm using pthreads;

Answer (score 2):

Run the program in `gdb` and when it crashes, use the `info threads` command to see the list of threads. The current thread is marked with `*`. Use `bt` to get the stack trace of the thread. See the [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html).

Comment: I never used gdb before, i will try it and post the result. 
Ps.: My main program have 3 threads, he systemcall another one using system("PROG_AUX &"); and this one is crashing. In this case I use gdb in which one? Is possible to call system("gdb PROG_AUX &"); or something like that?

Comment: `system` is not a syscall (although it will internally call some syscalls). Do you start all the threads via `system("...&");`? Then you actually start new processes which in turn start a thread. Use `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG` on `system`'s return value to determine whether the child process crashed, and display an error. That way you know which child crashed.

Comment: No, I start the threads with pthread_create(). It is a big project, made to run on 3 CPU's, but I'm running on my PC only for tests (because of corona). I Switch the routines that start the process on other CPUs to systemcall().

Comment: You don't need `system()` to run things on different CPUs; threads started by `pthread_create` may also run on different CPUs.

Comment: Btw, how do you know when a subprocess terminates?

Comment: You probably have to run the crashing subprocess directly via GDB, without the parent process that does `system()`.

Comment: _You don't need system() to run things on different CPUs;_
I didn't know that. I'm using a different system to run on another CPU. 

_how do you know when a subprocess terminates?_
Well, I don't know. this is the problem. To another process, I usually ping it every x secs to check, but I don't know how to check threads

Comment: _without the parent process_ 
The bug don't happen when i don't run the main routine. When I run everything normally and run the bugged process on terminal normally or using gdb it don't happen. The bug must be a synchronization problem, if I change the order and put a lot of sleeps, the bug also don't happen

Comment: I tried for the last 30min, maybe unluck, but i don't believe on that

Comment: `To another process, I usually ping it every x secs to check, but I don't know how to check thread` again, `system()` doesn't just start a thread, but a process. Why don't you "ping" the process you created? A better way would be to start the process with `fork` and check it via `waitpid`; check its return code to see whether it crashed, then you know which process failed. I think you have a wrong understanding of threads and processes.

Comment: To check if a **process** is alive, I send a TCP message because it may be on other CPU (every process has a thread dedicated to manage this). I don't know how to check if a **thread (subprocess)** is alive. I know that system() don't create threads, I never said that. Also, I know which process is crashing and know when it falls, But I don't know which thread on the process is crashing, therefore, I don't know where to look for the bug. Sorry, my English is not very good and maybe I was not able to express myself correctly.

Comment: "To check if a process is alive, I send a TCP message because it may be on other CPU" _Way_ too complicated. Just use `waitpid()`! "I don't know how to check if a thread (subprocess) is alive" - A thread is a very different thing from a subprocess. You check for threads with `pthread_join`, and for processes with `waitpid`. "But I don't know which thread on the process is crashing". Start the process in GDB directly (instead of `system()`) OR attach to the running process using the `attach` command and use `info threads` and `bt` to find the thread that crashes.

Comment: Oks, i will change to waitpid(), it is really to much for low gain. I tried to start the process directly on gdb and the crash didn't occur. And I use **pthread_join** to synchronize at the end of the program to finish everything. I didn't know that i can get the thread status using it. I will try now. Thanks for the Help.